# YouTube API search by keywords and category id

Tags: api, request, youtube-api

I'm trying to search videos by category id and keywords.

Here is my link:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key=API_KEYs&videoCategoryId=10&q=bieber
```

I'm getting:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.search",
    "reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
    "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": ""
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions."
 }
}
```

What i should change in my api request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data API has a unified search, meaning, search returns videos, playlists and channels. To filter by video specific parameters like videoCategoryId, you have to define **"type=video"**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=bieber&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```